# SquashFS mksquashfs segfault while compressing

Tags: ubuntu, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to create SquashFS partition under Ubuntu 11.04 (1TB harddisk, 8Gb RAM). 
Source folder contains 91Gb html files (several mirrored websites).

Trying to do this:

```
mksquashfs content_folder content.xz.sfs -comp xz
OR
mksquashfs content_folder content.gz.sfs
```

After several hours of processing i'm getting: 7.4Gb content.xz.sfs OR 9.1Gb content.gz.sfs
But I can't mount them:

```
root@server:/backup# file content.xz.sfs
content.xz.sfs: data

root@server:/backup# mount -t squashfs -o loop content.xz.sfs /mnt/sfs
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

Last output line of mksquashfs (no stats at end):

```
[=======================================================-] 5296672/5296672 100%
```

Dmesg:

```
dmesg | tail
[3118916.840011] mksquashfs[14787]: segfault at 7fff08e20300 ip 0000000000406c46 sp 00007fff08e20300 error 6 in mksquashfs[400000+1e000]
```

Tried to repeat this process several times but i'm always getting segfault at 100% of compressing.

**UPDATE:** I just have got the same segfault at the stage of 100% under FreeBSD 8.1 (squashfs-tools 4.0)

Seems like this is mksquashfs bug

Comment: I have exactly the same issue Anton has reported. root@c1p8# mksquashfs /dir/ dir.sqfs -noI -noD -noF -noX -no-duplicates [====================================================================================================/] 8556384/8556384 100%Segmentation fault As you can see I already tried with -no-duplicates option. Moreover, the final squashfs file is unusable: root@c1p8# ll -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 957203714044 Feb 14 16:12 dir.sqfs drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 6 Feb 14 22:14 test root@c1p8# mount -t squashfs dir.sqfs test/ -o loop mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the newest version of squashfs-tools, 4.2? At least one version had an occasional bug with duplicate file detection. You could also try passing the '-no-duplicates' argument to mksquashfs.